# VBA: UserForm How to calculate the Average from a list box in the second column using an array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having trouble finding a way that takes the average from a list box and then displaying that average on the user form. I know you are supposed to use an array, but I am very confused at the moment how to array a second column on a list box. Below is an example the numbers in the text box need to be averaged up and then displayed in the circle I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help clarify, it adds a Click Event Method to the ListBox ... so click on an entry in the ListBox and the messages tell you what they know about it

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
   MsgBox Me.ListBox1.Value
   MsgBox Me.ListBox1.ListIndex
   MsgBox Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)  ' The Value of Column 1
   MsgBox Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)  ' The Value of Column 2
End Sub
```

Alternatively if you want to know the overall average you just add all column 2 entries and divide by the number of entries there are

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim iMax As Long
   Dim SubTot As Double
   
   SubTot = 0
   iMax = UBound(Me.ListBox1.List)
   For i = 0 To iMax
      SubTot = SubTot + Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1)
   Next i
   MsgBox "The Average of ALL people is " & Round((SubTot / (iMax + 1)), 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get Average From a List Box Column

- This example uses an Active-X list box and label on a worksheet. Surely you'll manage to apply this to your user form case.
- It uses a loop to write the numbers from the 2nd column of the list box to an array and `Application.Average` to retrieve the average from the array and write it to the label.

```vb
Sub ListBoxAverage()
    
    Dim Players() As Variant: Players = VBA.Array("Tim", "Jon", "Sue")
    Dim Numbers() As Variant: Numbers = VBA.Array(1, 2, 4)
    
    Dim rUpper As Long: rUpper = UBound(Players)
    
    Dim Arr() As Double ' Array to Hold the Numbers
    Dim r As Long ' List Box Row Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Array Element Counter
    
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        ' Populate.
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        For r = 0 To rUpper
            .AddItem
            .List(r, 0) = Players(r) ' 1st column
            .List(r, 1) = Numbers(r) ' 2nd column
        Next r
        ' Write the values from the 2nd column to a Double array.
        ReDim Arr(0 To rUpper)
        Dim rValue As Variant
        For r = 0 To rUpper ' .ListCount - 1
            rValue = .List(r, 1) ' 2nd column
            If IsNumeric(rValue) Then ' it's a number
                Arr(n) = CDbl(rValue)
                n = n + 1
            'Else ' it's not a number; do nothing
            End If
        Next r
    End With
    
    With Sheet1.Label1
        ' Write the average to the label.
        If n = 0 Then
            .Caption = "No average."
        Else
            If n < r Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To n - 1)
            End If
            .Caption = Format(Application.Average(Arr), "0.0")
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```